# JSF redirect to same URL with different parameters

Tags: jsf, url, redirect, parameters

I have the following site structure:

```
web
|_events
   |_view.xhtml
|_news
   |_view.xhtml
|_pages
   |_view.xhtml
...
```

When a user clicks a link to, let's say, **Event #4**, he will be redirected to e.g. http://example.com/events/view.xhtml?itemId=4
On the **event->view.xhtml** page I have a menu with links to some other events (somehow related to the event that is currently viewed). Let's say those are **Event #1** and **Event #2**.
Currently my menu links have **value="../event/view.xhtml?itemId=#{row.id}"**. When it's clicked, the user will be redirected to e.g. http://example.com/events/view.xhtml?itemId=2
But if I use this approach (with "**../event/**" in the URL), it means that I have to create two more link types, with URLs for news and for pages. And also for every other item type that I make...
Is there any way to put only "**itemId=X**", i.e. only the new parameter value in the link value? Then I could use one menu template for every item type on my site.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a List in ApplicationScope or SessionScope according to your use case and add all the type there.

Something like

```
 public class Type implements Serializable {
     private String name;
     private List<Integer> items;
     //getters and setters
 }
```

Managed Bean

```
 public class TestBean {
      private List<Type> types;
      @PostConstruct
      public void init(){
          //constructTypesAccordingToSomeLogic();
      }
      //getters and setter
 }
```

View

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.types}" var="type">
      <ui:repeat value="#{type.items}" var="item">
            <h:outputLink value="../#{type.name}.xhtml?itemId=#{item}"></h:outpuLink>
      </ui:repeat>
 </ui:repeat>
```